# Differenciate between Principal component and eigenvectors

Tags: statistics

I am a bit confused about two concepts (Principal components and Eigenvectors).
When we can say that the principal components are identical to the eigenvectors of covariance matrix ? I just read in an article that the first eigenvector is the same as the first principal component, is that really correct and does that holds for all eigenvecotrs ( I mean, in particular, eigenvectors of covariance matrices)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Eigenvectors are a general concept in linear algebra.  You can find the eigenvectors of any matrix.  Principal components are the eigenvectors of a covariance matrix.  If you order the eigenvectors by the corresonding eigenvalue (the first eigenvector is the one that has the largest eigenvalue, the second has the second-largest eigenvalue, etc.) then they are the same as principal components.